# TypeScript constructor in interface

Tags: typescript

The [typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) says something about the following code:

```
interface ClockConstructor {
    new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
}
interface ClockInterface {
    tick();
}

function createClock(ctor: ClockConstructor, hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface {
    return new ctor(hour, minute);
}

class DigitalClock implements ClockInterface {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("beep beep");
    }
}
class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("tick tock");
    }
}

let digital = createClock(DigitalClock, 12, 17);
let analog = createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32);
```

...

> Because createClock’s first parameter is of type ClockConstructor, in
>   createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32), it checks that AnalogClock has the
>   correct constructor signature.

However, compiling the same code *without* the constructor, does not throw an error like you can see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ClockConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20(hour%3A%20number%2C%20minute%3A%20number)%3A%20ClockInterface%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20ClockInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tick()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createClock(ctor%3A%20ClockConstructor%2C%20hour%3A%20number%2C%20minute%3A%20number)%3A%20ClockInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20ctor(hour%2C%20minute)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20DigitalClock%20implements%20ClockInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tick()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22beep%20beep%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20AnalogClock%20implements%20ClockInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tick()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22tick%20tock%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20digital%20%3D%20createClock(DigitalClock%2C%2012%2C%2017)%3B%0D%0Alet%20analog%20%3D%20createClock(AnalogClock%2C%207%2C%2032)%3B)

Why is that? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not having a constructor in the ts class will still create one in the compiled js:

```
class DigitalClock implements ClockInterface {
    tick() {
        console.log("beep beep");
    }
}
```

Compiles into:

```
var DigitalClock = (function () {
    function DigitalClock() {
    }
    DigitalClock.prototype.tick = function () {
        console.log("beep beep");
    };
    return DigitalClock;
}());
```

So there's a constructor there which doesn't receive any arguments, but in javascript you can still call a function that doesn't declare any arguments with arguments:

```
function fn() {
    console.log(arguments);
}
fn(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]
```

In this case however typescript will complain about calling `fn` with arguments.
But this will be ok:

```
type MyFunction = { (a: number, b: number, c: number): void }

(fn as MyFunction)(1, 2, 3);
```

I guess that the compiler just trusts you that you know what you are doing, as the ctor exists and you can in fact get those arguments from the `arguments` object.

This how ever will fail:

```
class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
    constructor(str: string) {}
    tick() {
        console.log("tick tock");
    }
}
let analog = createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32);
```

Because now there's a different ctor signature.